# PHPexcel write to next blank row?

Tags: php, excel

I have the following code

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("untitled.xls");
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) //loop through the 3 worksheets of KindleEditionEISBN
{
$sheet_name = $worksheet->getTitle();  

if ($worksheet->getTitle = 'Records')
{
$highestColumm = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestColumn();
$highestRow = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();
```

And my `untitled.xls` file looks like this (skip an column, value in every even column)

```
          Column    A       B       C     D      E     F     G    H   I .... V
1st row        
2nd Row                   (value)      (value)      (value)     (value)
```

What I would like to do is to write my variables to the next blank row on each run-time so my data is formatted like this

```
          Column    A       B       C     D      E     F     G    H   I .... V
1st row        
2nd Row                   (value)      (value)      (value)     (value)
3rd Row                   (new value)  (new value) ....
```

so far from what I researched [PHPExcel Column Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577856/phpexcel-column-loop), the functions getHighestColumn(); & getHighestRow(); return the last row/column that is filled? can I then use this with the function setCellValueByColumnAndRow or am I missing something

Answer (score 2):

`getHighestRow()` returns the highest row number that contains `something`, but that `something` mat not be a data value: it could be that a cell in that row contains style information, or is referenced in a named range, or a print area, or whatever.

It's quick and efficient because it's determined when the spreadsheet is loaded, but isn't updated as you add data to the worksheet.

`getHighestDataRow()` returns the highest row number that contains actual cell `data`.

This is less efficient, as it is calculated every time it's called by checking the actual cells; but it does mean that it's always correct.

Comment: so getHighestDataRow() & getHighestDataColumn() ?

Comment: Assuming that there's a possibility your worksheets may contain styling or other information in rows below the lowest data containing row, then yes; otherwise use getHighestRow() because it's faster