# Search a cell by string in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, doc, phpexcelreader

I want to know if it's possible to get a cell by its name in an xls document, I mean Ii have this info in a excel file:

[image]

Normally to get the coordinate of the cell with the value "ASUS"

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B3')->getValue();
```

my problem is that users send my this excel file, and sometimes the rows are in disorder, e.g the row B3 sometimes appear in a different row like "B6" or "B7" or "B5", how I can get the cell "ASUS" getting by cell name "Modelo"

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing built-in to PHPExcel to do a search, but using the following example, it can do well for your problem.

```
$foundInCells = array();
$searchTerm = 'ASUS';

foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $CurrentWorksheet) {
 $ws = $CurrentWorksheet->getTitle();

 foreach ($CurrentWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {

    $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(true);

    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {

        if ($cell->getValue() == $searchTerm) {

            $foundInCells[] = $ws . '!' . $cell->getCoordinate();
            }
        }
    }
}
var_dump($foundInCells);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to loop through the entire file to find it just like searching a value in a 2D array.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5578240/4804118)