# PHPExcel mergeCells every 2n column

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have some data in array `$header1`, `$header2` and `$data`. The case is to insert all these arrays to excel file where header is already ready, that is:

[image]

Another headers will be set after inserting of `$header1` and `$header2`. 
Now the main issue is to insert `$header1` array to merged column:

[image]

Or first insert data and then merge them:

[image]

From my side I have tried a lot of solutions , but nothing...

**MY CODE :**

```
$excel2->setActiveSheetIndex(4);
$row = 6;
$col = 2;
$col_letter = 'D';
foreach($header1 as $key=>$value) {
    $excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value);
    $col=$col+2;
    $merge = "'".$col_letter.$row.":".(++$col_letter).$row."'";
    $excel2->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($merge);
    $col_letter++;
}
```

Take into account that `$header1` array's data is unpredictable and the count of data can be over 50.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Seems I have solved issue myself referring to [PHPExcel Column Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577856/phpexcel-column-loop?rq=1)

```
$row = 26;
$col = 2;
$j = 'C';
foreach($hesablar as $key=>$value) {
    $excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value);
    $col=$col+2;
    $i = $j++;
    $excel2->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($i.$row.':'.$j.$row);
    echo $i.$row.':'.$j.$row.'<br />';
    $j++;
}
```

[image]